# Is there a data structure that can perform range modulo additions and range minimum queries?

Tags: algorithms, data-structures

It is well-known that the Segment Tree performs range additions and range minimum queries in *O(logN)* each.

Let each element in the array have value *V[i]*, *M[i]*. We define a "range modulo add" as the following: add *+X* to *V[i]* for each element in the range *L<=i<=R* and then calculate modulo *M[i]* for each element *L<=i<=R*. Can both this operation and range minimum queries be run in (worst-case or average-case) *o(N)*? If not on ranges *[L,R]*, is it possible to handle range minimum queries and range modulo adds on the entire array quickly?

EDIT: There are two separate operations here. One is `void range_add(L,R,X)` which adds X to every element L<=i<=R, and then takes every element L<=i<=R modulo M[i]. The second is `int rmq(L,R)` which finds the smallest element in the range [L,R].

Here is an example of how it may operate, for clarity:

Let the starting (1-indexed) array be:
V = {1,2,3,4,5}
M = {5,4,6,2,8}

After range_add(1,3,4), the array V looks like this (the array M is always unchanged):
V = {0,2,1,4,5}
Note that indexes all the indexes from 1 to 3 exceeded their M-value after the addition, and were taken modulo their M-value.

After this, rmq(2,4) would return 1.

Please note that values X may be negative. If the value of a V[i] is reduced to below 0, then it becomes positive - eg. if V[i]=-1 and M[i]=4, V[i] will become 3.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm interpreting your query properly. Is it like this? $query(X, L, R) = \min_{L \leq i \leq R} (V[i] + X)\% M[i]$?

Comment: @CurtisF I have edited the question for more clarity.
Though, if you have a solution for the query you describe, I wouldn't mind either...

Comment: Do you know anything about the case where you only apply both update and query globally?

Comment: @DmitriUrbanowicz Unfortunately, no... If there is a restriction on the number of prime factors or similar it is possible, but that doesn't help very much with the full solution.

Comment: Edit: Unfortunately, it turns out that the way I wanted to do it with a restriction on prime factors is actually incorrect.